# setxkbmap, non-Latin layouts and keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl-C

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04. I wasn't quite satisfied with how it handles keyboard layouts (because you can't add more than four layouts, or at least I couldn't find how to do it), so I've just defined some keyboard shortcuts for commands like `setxkbmap -layout ua`. It works.

A problem appears when I switch with `setxkbmap` to a non-Latin layout: keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> work in some applications (Skype, Chrome, VS Code...) but not in others (mousepad, GNOME Terminal, Gummi...). If I use the default xfce4 mechanisms to switch between layouts, keyboard shortcuts work correctly everywhere (except Emacs, but it has its own ways to fix it, so it's less annoying).

Knowing that it somehow is possible, I tried to reimplement the behaviour myself with `xbindkeys` by mapping things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>м</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. However, applications seem to just ignore my attempts to send them fake key presses, whether I do it with `xvkbd -text "\Cv"`, `xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\Cv"`  or `xdotool key $(xdotool getwindowfocus) "Control_L+v"`. Why is it like that and what can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I should have done it like this: `setxkbmap -layout ua,de`, then it's possible to type like the layout is `ua` but the shortcuts work like the layout is `de`.